# How to swap between imagemaps with different sounds and coordinates

Tags: javascript, html, imagemap

I'm trying to make a super simple image map which is supposed to play certain sounds if you press a certain area. For example, pressing the water in a river makes a river sound.

That part is done but now I'm trying to **swap an image map and replace it with another by the press of a button or area on the imagemap**.

Let's say there is a picture of a winter landscape which has winter sounds. In a corner I want a button which swaps the imagemap and replaces it with a new one with summer sounds and a summer picture.

How do I go about doing this?

How the image map looks/works:

```js
var snd = new Audio("spring.mp3");
var rnd = new Audio("river.mp3");
var pnd = new Audio("rain.mp3");
var ond = new Audio("thunderrain.mp3");

function myFunction(){
    snd.play();
    snd.loop = true;
}
function myFunctiontwo(){
    rnd.play();
    rnd.loop = true;
}
function myFunctionthree(){
    pnd.play();
    pnd.loop = true;
}
function myFunctionfour(){
    lnd.play();
    lnd.loop = true;
}
function myFunctionfive(){
    snd.pause();
    rnd.pause();
    pnd.pause();
    ond.pause();
    lnd.pause();
}
```

```html
<img src="ambientbackground.jpg" usemap="#ambientmap" width="100%" height="100%" margin="0" padding="0" position="absolute">

<map name="ambientmap">
    <area shape= "rect" coords="100,300,1400,500" onclick='myFunction()'> 
    <area shape= "rect" coords="100,800,1400,400" onclick='myFunctiontwo()'>
    <area shape="rect" coords="100,0,1400,300" onclick='myFunctionthree()' ondblclick='myFunctionfour()'>
    <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,100,500" onclick='myFunctionfive()'>
</map>
```